# What does String... params mean?

Tags: java

I am following a book and got the below code:

```
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> 
    {    
         @Override         
         protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) 
         {             
             String url = params[0]; 
             // ...
         }
    }
```

What does `String... params` (parameter of `doInBackground()` method) do?

Comment: it means you can use.. `doItBackground("Hello")` or `doItBackground("Hello", "World")` .. Not to be confused with arrays parameter.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Answer (score 0):

This is known as Varargs and you can read more in the docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

In short it means you can pass the final argument as a sequence of individual arguments or an array.